# Which algorithms are the best choices for my binary classification problem?

Tags: classification, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

Which algorithms are the best choices for my binary classification problem? 
I have approximately 200 K samples in the training set and 18 attributes, including binary, numeric and categorical.

I would like to get the list of top three algorithms that fit my problem.

Comment: Read about the ( no free lunch theorem)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to know beforehand which algorithm is best, maybe your problem is so complicated even a 50 layer NN could not solve it, you just have to try, but visualizations usually help to understand your it.

I would begin though with simple models as SVMs, Logistic Regression or Decision Trees/Random Forest. Don't forget to try with different kernels for the SVMs.

Comment: my problem is predicting whether a health insurance claim is acceptable for reimbursement or rejected. As you can see, my problem has 18 features with more than 200 K dataset. I guess this may help to get more of your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I hope it still helps, but since consumers may ask you why their reimbursement was rejected I think you need a highly interpretable model, so my prefered solution would be a tree based.